# Curl PHP Basic HTTP Authentication return 405 error

Tags: php, codeigniter, http, authentication, curl

The method

```
/user/role/authenticate
```

on my webserver API does require HTTP authentification in form of username and password.

I use the following code to access the API of my webserver from a different frontend, that is designed with CodeIgniter.

```
$URL='http://.../user/role/authenticate'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30); //timeout after 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "testusername:testpassword");
$result=curl_exec ($ch);        
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
echo $status_code;
print_r($result);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But I get the result ,,405: Method not allowed".

What to do?

Comment: GET is the default method; have you tried with: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

Comment: Can I just add this line of code ? Or do I have to modify someting?

Answer (score 0):

authentication need post method.

this example from my curl header

```
"authorization: Basic ". base64_encode($username.':'.$password),
```

base64 is optional, depend ur API auth